# Foreach mysqli delete loop trouble

Tags: php, checkbox, mysqli, foreach

I'm very close to solving my problem, this is where I'm at:

```
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<tr><td align="left">' .
        $row['title'] . '</td><td align="left">'
        . $row['genre'] . '</td><td align="left">'
        . $row['length'] . '</td><td align="left">'
        . $row['created'] . '</td><td align="left">'
        . $row['views'] . '</td><td align="left">' //. var_dump($row) //dump row value for testing
        . '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"  value= "'.$row['upload_id'].'"'.' />'.' </td>'. '</tr>';



    }
    echo '</table>'; // Close the table
```

and the delete functions:

```
function submit_delete() {
  if(!is_null($_POST['delete']) && !is_null($_POST['checkbox'])) { //Check to see if a delete command has been submitted.
    //This will dump your checkbox array to your screen if the submit works.
    //You can manually check to see if you're getting the correct array with values
    var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);//Comment this out once it's working.
    deleteUploads($id_array);

  }
  else {
    echo "Error: submit_delete called without valid checkbox delete.";var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);
  }
}


    function deleteUploads ($id_array) {
      if (count($id_array) <= 0) {   echo "Error: No deletes in id_array!"; var_dump($_POST['checkbox']); return; }//bail if its empty
      $delete_success = false;
      foreach ($id_array as &$id) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM `upload` WHERE `upload_id`=$id AND `owner_id`={$_SESSION['user_id']}";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        if ($result) { $delete_success = true; }
      }

      if($delete_success) {
        header('Location: newwriter_profile.php');
      } else {
        echo "Error: ".mysqli_error();
      }
    }


    //Test deleteUploads (remove once you know the function is working)
    //$test_ids = array();
    //$test_ids[] = 5;//make sure this id is in the db
    //$test_ids[] = 7;//this one too
    submit_delete();
    //deleteUploads($id_array);//should remove ids 10 and 9//

    mysqli_close($dbc);
```

I have determined that `id_array` is not getting the correct `$_POST` values for the checkbox.  The vardump shows that it has the correct upload ids, then I vardump `id_array` and it shows NULL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CURRENTLY:

```
        function submit_delete() {
  if(!is_null($_POST['delete']) && !is_null($_POST['checkbox'])) { //Check to see if a delete command has been submitted.
    //This will dump your checkbox array to your screen if the submit works.
    //You can manually check to see if you're getting the correct array with values
   // var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);//Comment this out once it's working.
    $id_array = $_POST['checkbox'];
    var_dump($id_array);
    deleteUploads($id_array);

  }
  else {
    echo "Error: submit_delete called without valid checkbox delete.";//var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);
  }
}


function deleteUploads ($id_array) {
  if (count($id_array) <= 0) {   echo "Error: No deletes in id_array!"; return; }//bail if its empty
  $delete_success = false;
  foreach ($id_array as $id) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `upload` WHERE `upload_id`=$id AND `owner_id`={$_SESSION['user_id']}";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    if ($result) { $delete_success = true; }
  }

  if($delete_success) {
    header('Location: newwriter_profile.php');
  } else {
    echo "Error: ".mysqli_error();
  }
}
```

I am getting correct vardump after the id_array=POST, but after I submit delete, the viewsource indicates that nothing after the end of my  is being read (sidebar and footer disappear). No errors are currently being reported.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anywhere where $id_array is assigned a value.  For example where you call :

```
deleteUploads($id_array)
```

there isn't a value assigned to $id_array at that point.

What value should $id_array have?  Is there a value in the $_POST array that you need to assign to $id_array?

Also I think there may be a misplaced '&' here:

```
foreach ($id_array as &$id)
```

I think it should just be:

```
foreach ($id_array as $id)
```

Comment: $id_array should have each $upload_id corresponding to which checkboxes are checked, after it has these values it steps through and runs the sql statement one at a time to remove them.

Comment: Ok - there might be some code I can't see where the value of $id_array is set, but unless $id_array has been declared as a global variable specifically, it will need to be set locally within the submit_delete function.

Comment: Trying adding print_r($id_array) as the first line in the deleteUploads function, and that will show you whether or not the variable contains any value when it arrives in that function.

Comment: I tried:        $id_array = array($_POST['checkbox']);
    var_dump($id_array);     $id_array seems to get the correct values according to the var_dump, but no deletion takes place.  Also, I had to change 'checkbox[]' to 'checkbox' in order to get the values. In doing so, it killed my html sidebar and footer which are below the </form> tag.

Comment: try passing POST directly to function `deleteUploads($_POST['checkbox']);` and see if values are passed

Comment: Is it the '&' in front of $id here:  foreach ($id_array as &$id)?

Comment: Where did you do this? --> "$id_array = array($_POST['checkbox']); var_dump($id_array); $id_array seems to get the correct values according to the var_dump".  Unless it was inside the submit_delete function or $id_array was a global, $id_array would not retain that value inside the function (variable scope).

Comment: I don't think the &$id would cause an issue since it's bailing before it gets to that point.  I made the $id_array = array() statement within the submit_delete function.

Comment: I'd suggest adding the updated code to your question so we can all see it.  Thx

Comment: var_dump within the foreach shows that $id_array is getting the right values.  Somehow, the array is lost between foreach and the sql statement. Execution gets stuck after the foreach and kills the rest of my html.